# How to properly do dynamic memory allocation (C++)

Tags: c++, memory

I am trying to create a dynamically allocated array and print it's contents in C++. Although my code is producing incredibly strange output when I print.

```
int main() {
    int* arr;

    arr = new int [1200];
    memset(arr, 5, 1200);

    for (int i = 0; i < 1200; i++)
        printf("%d ", arr[i]);

    std::cout << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

Mixing the cout and printf was just because I was playing around with the code. All the proper includes are in my file.\

Here is the output:

```
84215045 84215045 84215045 84215045 84215045 84215045 84215045 84215045 84215045 84215045 84215045 84215045 1285 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

I have no idea how this was produced.

EDIT:

Thank you everyone for the answers. I now understand what my code does and why the output looks the way that it look.Great answers.

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/memset

Comment: `memset()` sets *bytes*, not `int`s.

Comment: Use [`std::array`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/array/array/) if your compiler supports c++11 else use [`std::vector`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/)

Comment: Use [`std::fill`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/fill) instead of `memset` is you want to set each element to a value.

Comment: What do you want? I mean what do you want initialized in the array?

Comment: Also, `printf` and `memset` are C, not C++ and you should avoid mixing C and C++ features unless you have a specific reason for doing so.

Comment: also note that you have `new` w/o `delete[]`

Comment: This question has nothing at all to do with dynamic allocation. Please consider changing the title.

Answer (score 2):

```
memset(arr, 5, 1200);
```

If you scribble a whole bunch of 5'a on a piece of paper and then try to read the paper, you'll get back things like "5555". 84215048 in hex is 0x05050505.

Don't manipulate arrays of data as if they were raw chunks of memory unless you know exactly what you're doing.

Answer (score 2):

Consider 84215045 byte by byte in hex and you will understand what happened:

```
84215045 = 05050505 (hex)
```

`memset` initializes every *byte* to `5`, but an integer is 4-byte long in your case. Also, `memset` expects the size in *bytes* of the memory region to fill, which is not `1200`, but `1200 * sizeof (int)`, which in your case appears to be `4800`. This explains the trailing zeroes as well.

You might initialize every element to `5` using a loop:

```
arr = new int [1200];
for (int i = 0; i < 1200; ++i) arr[i] = 0;
```

or with pointers:

```
arr = new int[1200];
for (int *cur = arr, *end = arr + 1200; cur < end; ++cur) *cur = 0;
```

Finally, consider doing away with direct allocation of arrays with `new` and using STL containers like `std::vector` if possible.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is setting each *byte* in the first part of the array, to 5. With a modern C++ compiler as of 2014 each `int` is 4 bytes or 8 bytes, with each byte 8 bits (although on some computers it can be 16 bits per byte). Assuming 8 bits per byte and 4 bytes per `int` you'd get the value ((5×256 + 5)×256 + 5)×256 + 5 =

```
C:\> set /a ((5*256 + 5)*256 + 5)*256 + 5
84215045
C:\> _
```

Here's how to do your program in the most natural way in C++:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

auto main() -> int
{
    vector<int> arr( 1200, 5 );
    for( int x : arr ) { cout << x << ' '; }
    cout << '\n';
}
```